# How do I display "N/A" instead of max and min values in an expression evaluation?

Tags: java, eclipse

My code works, but what I need it to do is when nothing is enter the evaluation for the highest and the lowest should be N/A. Right now all it displays is the max and min number when something isn't entered.

Example:

```
Press K for keyboard or F to read expressions from a file OR escape to exit:
k
Please Enter a Post-Fix Expression (eg: 5 2 *)

Application Closed
Evaluations complete....
Highest Value: -3.4028235E38
Lowest Value: 3.4028235E38
Agregate result: 0.0
Average result: NaN
Valid expressions: 0.0
Invalid Expressions: 0.0
```

I need the ones in bold to say n/a but i don't know how.

```
private  static void keyboardService(){

    while (true){
        System.out.println("Please Enter a Post-Fix Expression (eg: 5 2 *)");
        String postfix=keyboard.nextLine();
        String [] elements =postfix.split(" ");

        if (postfix.equals("")){
            System.out.println("Application Closed");
            evaluation(); 
            System.exit(0);
        } 


        if (elements.length == 3){

            try{


                num1 = Float.valueOf(elements[0]);
                num2 = Float.valueOf(elements[1]);
                float total;    
                if(elements[2].equals("+")){
                    total = num1 + num2;
                    display(total + " = " + num1 + elements[2] + num2);
                    valid_count = valid_count + 1;
                    calc(total);
                }
                else if(elements[2].equals("*")){
                    total = num1 * num2;
                    display(total + " = " + num1 + elements[2] + num2);
                    valid_count = valid_count + 1;
                    calc(total);
                }
                else if(elements[2].equals("/")){
                    total = num1 / num2;
                    display(total + " = " + num1 + elements[2] + num2);
                    valid_count = valid_count + 1;
                    calc(total);
                }
                else if(elements[2].equals("-")){
                    total = num1 - num2;
                    display(total + " = " + num1 + elements[2] + num2);
                    valid_count = valid_count + 1;
                    calc(total);


                }

                else{
                    display("Error Invalid Expression: "+ postfix);{
                        invalid_count = invalid_count + 1;
                    }


                }} catch(NumberFormatException e){

                    display("Error Invalid Expresion: "+postfix);
                    invalid_count = invalid_count + 1;
                } //end of second if

        } else {
            display("Error Invalid Expression: "+ postfix);
            invalid_count = invalid_count + 1;
        }

    }

}//end of keyboard service  

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private static void calc(float total){


    highest = Math.max(highest, total );
    lowest= Math.min(lowest, total);
    aggregate = aggregate + total; 

}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   
private static void evaluation(){


    display("Evaluations complete...."); 

    display("Highest Value: " + highest);
    display("Lowest Value: " + lowest);
    display("Agregate result: " + aggregate );
    display("Average result: " + aggregate/valid_count);
    display("Valid expressions: " + valid_count);
    display("Invalid Expressions: " + invalid_count);


}


}
```

Comment: Where do you assign the initial value to `highest` and `lowest`?

Comment: Ive assigned it right at the top but i havent put all of the code on

Comment: its just like this  private static float highest = -Float.MAX_VALUE;
       private static float lowest = Float.MAX_VALUE;

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
display("Highest Value: " + (highest == Float.MIN_VALUE ? "N/A" : String.valueOf(highest)));
display("Lowest Value: " + (lowest == Float.MAX_VALUE ? "N/A" : String.valueOf(lowest)));
and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

In the evaluation method, before you print, check highest and lowest.

```
if (highest < 0)
    display("Highest Value: " + "N/A");
else
    display("Highest Value: " + highest);
```

Comment: why not just `display("Highest Value: N/A");`

Answer (score 0):

Beside the fact that a better structure for you code would be the prefered solution you could achieve it with following changes in your code.

in your method ` keyboardService()

```
...
String [] elements =postfix.split(" ");
boolean validInput = true;
if (postfix.equals("")){
    validInput = false;
```

in your method `evaluation()`

```
display("Highest Value: " + (validInput ? highest : "n/a"));
display("Lowest Value: " + (validInput ? lowest : "n/a"));
display("Agregate result: " + (validInput ? aggregate : "n/a"));
display("Average result: " + (validInput ? aggregate / valid_count : "n/a"));
display("Valid expressions: " + valid_count);
display("Invalid Expressions: " + invalid_count);
```